# How do I start off with integral functional questions like these?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, definite-integrals

I saw this question in *Advanced Problems in Mathematics by Vikas Gupta*

> **If $f^{\prime}(x)=f(x)+\int_0^1 f(x) d x$ and given $f(0)=1$, then
> $\int f(x) d x$ is equal to** :

I have no clue to on how to solve questions like these. Despite, I tried to make an attempt:
I first took **$\int_0^1 f(x) d x=K$** as it is going to be a fixed value and simplified the expression as **$f^{\prime}(x)=f(x) + K$**. Then I integrated the LHS and the RHS and substituted $x=0$ and got the integral constant **C**=$1/2$

Could any please advice on how to proceed. And if there is some sort of a specific method on how we tackle problems like these, please let me know. Many thanks

Comment: Please edit your post to include your intermediate step, i.e. what you found when integrating $f^{\prime}(x)=f(x) + K.$ This will help us to give you a more specific and pedagogic help, rather than spoon-feeding you with a complete answer which does not stick to what you already did.

Comment: Identical question (with answers) found easily [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%5E%7B%5Cprime%7D(x)%3Df(x)%2B%5Cint_0%5E1%20f(x)%20d%20x%24)

Comment: However, I maintain my request to the OP. (I do not intend to edit such a dedicated "pedogogic help" as an answer but as a comment.) Moreover, the answers in the duplicate are far from illuminating. @MartinR

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes Ma'am I will edit it for sure. I only have my phone with me at the moment so latex is a bit exhausting on the mini screen. Once I use my pc I will edit it in my free time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you differentiate the given identity, you get $f''-f' = 0$, which has the general solution $f(x) = c_1 + c_2 e^x$. Additionally, you know that

1. $f(0)=1$, hence $c_1+c_2=1$.
2. $f'(0)=f(0)+\int_0^1 f(x) dx \Rightarrow 2c_1 +(e-1) c_2 = 0$

With this information you can compute $c_1, c_2$ and have the expression for $f$. The value of the integral is now given by $f'(0)-f(0)$.

Comment: Why $(e-2)$ and not $(e-1)?$ Anyway, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C=\int_0^{1}f(x)dx$. Then $f'(x)=f(x)+C$. This gives $(e^{-x}f(x))'=e^{-x}f'(x)-e^{-x}f(x)=Ce^{-x}$. [This is a standard trick: See "Integrating factor" in Wikipedia].

Integrating this we  get $f(x)=-C+De^{x}$ where $D$ is a constant. Now use the coniditions $f(0)=1$ and $C=\int_0^{1}f(x)dx$ to find the values of $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Hi! I really appreciate this answer too!